# Weird behavior with filename in /proc/pid/stat

Tags: c, debian

I have a weird behavior with the value of filename in /proc/pid/stat.

My program's name is "test_dev", and when I execute it with "./test_dev" and i look on /proc/pid/stat, i see "pid (test) ....".
Same in /proc/pid/status.

I change "test_dev" to "testdev" to see if the underscore is the culprit of this mess, but the same thing appear again.

I printf argv[0], and I correctly see "test_dev" (or "testdev").

I wonder how the field in stat is set, and why it's incomplet, because the man of /proc say that is the filename of the executable.

I think a little, and I wonder if Eclipse can be the culprit.
This EDI gave me some surprise sometimes, and I won't be surprised if this is the case again, even if it really bug me that argv[0] and /proc/pid/stat have not the same value.

Is somebody have an explanation ?

thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should copy&paste the relevant parts of your terminal output (including the commands you execute to a) Start your program and b) display the entries of stat.

Comment: Here the command line :

root@123456789012:/home# ./testdev&
[2] 29012
root@123456789012:/home#
./testdev || testdev || testdev
cat /proc/29012/stat
29012 (test) S ...
root@123456789012:/home/cpadmin# killall test*
test: no process found
test_dev: no process found
test._dev: no process found

I tried a new test this morning with a newproject test, an everything work fine. So it's either my program or the computer. The problem is I don't really know the computer I work with. It's Debian 8, I just know that.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the real filename without "_dev" is 15 character long, and
>   the "comm" field seem to be limited by the kernel to 15 character long
>   ... So, the filename is truncated in /proc/pid/stat, …   Where can I
>   find this kind of documentation ?

Unfortunately, this seems to be not well documented where one would expect it, but there are some hints here and there on the [`proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page.

```
       /proc/[pid]/comm (since Linux 2.6.33)
              …  Strings longer than TASK_COMM_LEN (16) characters are silently truncated.
```

```
       /proc/[pid]/stat
              Status information about the process.  This is used by ps(1).
              It is defined in the kernel source file fs/proc/array.c.
```

[`TASK_COMM_LEN`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/TASK_COMM_LEN) and the [`task_struct`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/task_struct) are defined in [include/linux/sched.h](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h):

```
#define TASK_COMM_LEN           16
…
struct task_struct {
…
    char                comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
```

The difference between the 15 characters you observe and the 16 here is due to the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The field in /proc/pid/stat you mention does not show argv[0], but the executed command. Probably, eclipse compiles the file to an executable named "test" and executes it.

This example:

```
execl("foo", "bar", "baz", NULL);
```

has a comm of "foo" (the thing in /proc/pid/stat), an argv[0] of "bar" and "baz" as argv[1]

To double-check that, you might try to call your program "xxxxx" and see, if it is still named "test" in /proc/pid/stat

Comment: I do not execute the program from Eclipse.
I compil it from Eclispe and then I type "/path/test_dev". The filename is clearly "test_dev". Thank for your answer, I really think argv[0] should be in /proc/pid/stat.

Comment: The filename is really test_dev? That's indeed strange, what system is that exactly?

Comment: No, argv[0] is definitively not the thing in /proc/pid/stat. It is the name of the executed command, which often differs. If you execute a command by shell, it _usually_ matches, but that's all

Comment: It's Debian 8, and yes, the filename is really "test_dev", that's why i'm really surprised by this kind of behavior. How can I change the name of the executed command within my C program ? I searched and I found it's by modify argv[0], but now I'm a little lost.

Comment: If you modify argv[0] some process tools like "ps" will reflect the change, but not /proc/pid/stat. That's why I am lost a bit, in my opinion, this value cannot ever change (apart from another successful call to execve), but is fixed to the filename of the binary, which was started by execve.

Comment: Apparently, you can use prctl with PR_SET_NAME to change the name in /proc/pid ...
I tested it and it's ok ! :)
The behavior with the wrong (or truncated) filename in /proc/pid/stat still bug me, and I really want to know why because I use /proc/pid/stat a lot (for knowing if there are already a process running, for example).

Comment: @Tom's correct, seems like this is another way, thanks for pointing that out! However, this is surely not what happens here.

Comment: I have to apologies to everyone. In reality, the filename is not "test_dev" but something that I don't want to type here (work related). However, the real filename without "_dev" is 15 character long, and the "comm" field seem to be limited by the kernel to 15 character long ... So, the filename is truncated in /proc/pid/stat, but not in /proc/pid/cmdline, and the prctl function with PR_SET_NAME work in that case also. 
The only thing that annoye me is that the kernel limitation isn't in the man page. Where can I find this kind of documentation ?

Again, sorry and thanks to you.